3-dimensional convex polytope with adjacent vertices is a 3-simlpex
Let $P=\rm{conv} ( \textit{V} )$ be an convex $3$-dimensional polytope with vertices $V$ in which every two vertices $x,y \in V$ are adjacent. Show that $P$ is a $3$-Simplex.
I think we can use radon's theorem to proof that the number of vertices can't be bigger than $4$, but I'm not sure how to do it.
My idea is the following: Let $V = \{ p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5 \} $. Then, by radon's theorem, there exists two non-empty subsets $P_1,P_2 \subseteq V$ with $P_1 \uplus P_2 = V$ such that $\rm{conv}(\textit{P}_1) \cap \rm{conv}(\textit{P}_2) \neq \varnothing$. So the only possibilities are $P_1 = \{ p_1 \} $ and $P_2 = \{ p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5 \} $ or $P_1 = \{ p_1, p_2 \} $ and $P_2 = \{ p_3,p_4,p_5 \} $. Since in the first case it is $p_1 \in \rm{conv}(\textit{P}_2)$, we can just delete $p_1$ to get just $4$ vertices again.
So we just have to show if $\rm{conv}(\{ \textit{p}_1, \textit{p}_2 \} ) \cap \rm{conv}(\{ \textit{p}_3, \textit{p}_4, \textit{p}_5 \} ) \neq \varnothing $, then $\rm{conv}(\{ \textit{p}_1, \textit{p}_2 \} )$ can't be an edge of $P$. How could we prove this?
